# Updates don't working on Windows10

Tags: windows, bash, windows-10, updates

This is my first question here. As I say in the title, I'm having some problems on updating to new *Windows10Home(64 bits) patches* (concretely, Windows shows up error messages regarding some of the patches).

I've tried register files modifications, restoring to a past version, and some Windows "console" commands (we know Linux's bashes are incredibly more complete); any of them worked. So, I just was wondering if I'm missing something, and that's the help I need, do you have some advices to give me? Thank you for taking your time.

**Note:** *I don't have any image of my own problem, but I've chosen a sample one, for better understanding: (credits: https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/windows-updates-activation/34341d1485956150t-windows-10-updates-fails-install-even-after-multiple-attempts-screenshot-15-.png)*.

[Sample]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OecG8.png *(I can't share direct images yet, sorry)*.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to windows is an independent process which can cause issue due to known bugs.You can try deleting your C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download and other folders in Software Distribution . This will help you to restart  the updating process. Clearing temp files via windows utility for freeing disk space may also remove files causing the issue. Updates may also not work if they get downloaded incorrectly or by some persons intention via p2p update download setting but deleting this download folder should do the job.

Comment: I will try your tips as soon as I get to my computer again, thank you so much.